# Why do they call it base 10?

Tags: soft-question, terminology, definition, number-systems

Now, I know intuitively why it's called base 10: because there's 10 numbers.

But see here's the thing, if we're working with numbers 0-9 (and of course we are), we use up our numerical artillery at 9. Why isn't it called base 9?

If it's because 10 is the number we round up to,that logic doesn't seem to transcend to other bases because every base would literally be called base 10 if we were to extend that logic.

So, in using a system with 9 unique characters, and calling it base 10, this leads to inconsistencies with every other single base. Take binary, base 2, it's called base 2 though uses 1 character, hexadecimal, called base 16, uses 15 char (1-9 [not 10 though] and A-E).

Now in binary, octal, and hexadecimal, it's not really an issue, but what about an arbitrary base n? What do we call it then?

We *could* assign a name to it like we have with 'base 2' i.e binary, but if we want to work within a new base, then to communicate you're working in base n, it becomes tedious.

The most logical thing to do, in my opinion, would be to call the base by the last unique number you have to work with. This is easier to remember, and resolves the issue of nomenclature.

Comment: It's because you're counting in powers of $10$

Comment: Aren't you doing that with any base though? if you're in base 8, you'd still be counting in base 10, only in base 8, what we call 10 in base 10 would be 11.in base 8, But it' still powers of 10, it's just that the idea of 10, has changed.

Comment: I think it is called base 10 since every number can be written as a linear combination of $10^k$, likewise base 2

Comment: I think the OP is trying to talk about the fact that the number $n$ written in base $n$ is "$10$" which we usually call "ten." We just need to separate the notation "10" from the actual number it represents when we change bases.

Comment: This question is why I generally try to write the name of our common numbering system as "base ten" or "the decimal system" instead of "base $10$".

Comment: @angryavian thank you! ^.^

Comment: I suppose our number system should be "base 10, base 10", where as your typical binary is "base 2, base 10." But then we would have to iterate that process forever. I agree with you, OP.

Comment: The boring answer is probably 'tradition'. But I agree with OP, and I have tried to use "base (9+1)" as alternative for "base 10", but that confused people who did not see the problem.

Comment: [Because it's always base $10$.](https://qph.is.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-c9468c7f3d7bcef7b0f2d0fdf83328d4?convert_to_webp=true)

Comment: @user2901512 *'what we call 10 in base 10 would be 11.in base 8'* Wrong, what we call 10 in base 10 would be **12** in base 8.

Comment: @Ciapan haha yep, your right. I've always thought of base 10 as base 9 ever since I first learned maths, so am always in that mode of thinking :D

Comment: Just count zero as a digit (because you actually use it!) and you'll get ten different digits, $0..9$, not nine $1..9$, hence the base is ten, not nine.

Comment: @Ciapan, actually, I have thought about this, as it would seem to resolve the issue due to there being 10 unique digits if 0 is included. However, there's a problem with that. 0 is the 1st number, 1 the 2nd, 2 the 3rd, and so on. So if we call 0 the first number, then we never have enough numbers to number all the numbers! I think that this makes sense however, as 1 is 0 to 1, since we start at 0. But still, what of 0? Well, in my view, it isn't really a numerical quantity, it's more of a concept, like infinity.

Comment: @user2901512 No, zero is as much of a number as 1, 2, 3, -1, -2, -3, 1.1, 2.2, 3.3,  etc.

Comment: When I tell you in English "This book is in French" I use the English word for French.  It doesn't matter that in French "French" is "Francais" and I didn't make a mistake when I said "French" instead of "Francais".... because I'm speaking in English!  Not French!  So if I'm counting in a number system based on powers of 7 and in this number system the basis of the number system is called 10 I say "I'm counting in base 7" instead of the base 7 "I'm counting in base 10".  Why?  Base 10 is our native system.  That's all.

Comment: @MKII, well, see, it's not. Don't get me wrong, I can see your logic, but 0 is different with respects to it's properties both in the real world and mathematically. So, in the real world, we can have say, 2 apples, 2 oranges, 2 humans etc, and abstract the idea of 2. However, we can't do this with 0. I mean yes, you can have 0 of something, but you can't interact with 0 things, and you can have always have 0 of anything. Furthermore, its mathematical properties are also different, for e.g it's not a factor of any number, you can't really divide by 0.

Comment: @Fleablood To extend your current analogy, the problem isn't what language is used, but the consistency within that language, which is necessary in any language, including that of mathematics. By calling numbers 1-9 (or maybe 0-9, it's debatable), this complicates the naming conventions for every other base for the sake of just one (even if said base is our native to us).

Comment: And we *are* consistent within our language.  We consistently acknowledge that our native base is the decimal base and that excursion to alternative bases is in context and clear when we start using the language and when we aren't.

Comment: It's called base 10 because it is the number of unique digits. The highest representation in base n is n-1 in your standard bases. Binary (base 2) has highest representation of 1, decimal (base 10) has highest representation of 9. Or in other words, n is the first non-unique representation in base n for these systems. Your understanding falls short because you disregard the digit 0 -- binary doesn't have 1 digit, it has 2 (0 and 1).

Comment: @Vegard Just because 0 is used in binary doesn't mean 0 is a digit, with a number like 101 in binary, 0 is just being reused, so no one would argue that 101 isn't a digit, but 0 alone, well it's debatable. Even when 0 by itself is used as an actual value, it's only when it's being used to represent logical truth.

Comment: Yes it does. 0 is a unique digit because that is what it is defined as. The number 101 in binary has no impact on this -- the string "0" is indeed being reused, but that was my whole point -- above the string "1", you have to start reusing representations because there are no more unique ones.

Comment: The representation "10" is not unique, because it is a concatenation of "1" and "0", but the value of the representation is still unique! That's both what number systems mean and why they exist at all.

Comment: @Vegard You can't say that something is so by definition, that's tautological. Anyway, I knew of your premise, I just didn't accept the conclusion.

Comment: There is no other digit in base 10 or base 2 that means "zero". Hence, 0 is unique.

Comment: It's not tautological as much as it is axiomatical.

Comment: @Vegard No it's definitely tautological, and it's not axiomatical because the definition of that is a fact whose truth can be accepted by intuition alone, and this has been under debate for many many years (we're not the first one's to take issue with this).

Comment: This is getting a bit off topic, but there's no debate over what the string "0" represents in base 10 or base 2 (or how unique it is), nor does a mathematical axiom have to be intuitive. I don't know where you get either of those from, but they probably warrant their own threads.

Comment: @Vegard, yeah, the whole thing has seriously sidetracked, we'll agree to disagree.

Comment: I downvoted this question. In my opinion, it seems like a very silly thing to do to call base 10 base 9. To me, this seems like a totally useless question.

Comment: Care to explain your reasoning?

Comment: I saw this question in related questions to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2778558/logic-behind-the-hexadecimal-number-system and until after I clicked it, I had no idea I had previously downvoted it so long ago. Now I see that it was a real question that although I couldn't understand the point of at that time, I can understand the point of now. You're suggesting that we have even more single digit characters such as $X$ for 10 and $\epsilon$ for 11 so that when people tell other people they are using base 10, they can do it by saying they are using base $X$. Otherwise, they may

Comment: think maybe they're using base 9 because if we were using base 9, we would still say we are using base 10. I guess since we say we are using base 10, I guess you are assuming we still would say we are using base 10 even if we were using base 9. I guess you don't know how to explain your question so you wrote why wouldn't we say we are using base 9 if we were using base 9 to mean why aren't we saying something like we're using base $X$ to mean we are using base 10. I think the reason is that everyone knows that we are using base 10 and not another base. Was your question something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name refers to the way we choose to group our items. The way we've evolved, we found that nine counting symbols and a symbol for nothing suffice for our preferred base. We're able to recycle the glyphs $1$ and $0$ to denote our grouping, which is given by the combined symbol $10$.

---

To illustrate why it's all about the grouping, and not about the final unique symbol, let's roll with this example. Pick an amount of symbols that can use to enumerate your fingers. You may prefer $$1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,X$$ but another could have just as easily chosen $\odot,\triangle,\square,\cup,\star,\vee,\uplus,\times,+,\LaTeX$. These are just glyphs at this point, markers for each of the fingers. For convenience, let's use my suggested set.

We have an issue, I want to add more symbols to keep track of toes. Okay, how about:

$$1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,X$$
$$1',2',3',4',5',6',7',8',9',X'$$

Man, that's a lot of symbols. I *like* the number of my fingers, $X$, and in fact, you could say I have $X$ toes. Wow, grouping things by $X$ is convenient, both physically and visually. Can I keep track of these groups by *repeating* my symbols to enumerate larger quantities in groups of $X$?

Well, it would be nice if I started counting from nothing, so let's add a symbol for that.
$$0$$
$$1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,X$$

Now, how should this work? Well, I can have $X$ objects. Or I can have $X$ *groups* of $X$ objects each. Or, wow, even $X$ groups of $X$ groups of $X$ objects! It seems like reaching $X$ marks a sort of *restart point*. I could denote this regrouping by saying I have $1$ $X$ and $0$ other stuff. Okay, I feel inspired. Let's combine those symbols to replace $X$:

$$0$$
$$1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10$$

And on and on it goes... This was more or less a colorful way of expressing BigBearzzz's answer: each digit's location denotes a higher grouping. We don't group every nine objects, though. We group ten objects.

---

What about other bases? Well, say we choose to group every three objects. We would still want a symbol for nothing, $0$, another for one $1$, for two $2$, and once again we can recycle our glyphs to call one group of three $10$. That's where we regroup. Note that these are just glyphs, recycled from the base ten representations. The meaning is different here than in base ten due to where I choose to regroup. Why is this *called* base three? Well, I'd like to refer to this new system, and I choose to borrow the name from a convenient source: my favorite base of all, ten.

Comment: So... it's a convention.

Answer (score 11):

This is more like a comment but it's too long, so I'm putting it as an answer instead, please accept my apology.

In base $10$, the "symbol" $78152_{10}$ represents the number

$78152_{10}=7\cdot 10^4 + 8\cdot 10^3 + 1\cdot 10^2 + 5\cdot 10^1 + 2\cdot 10^0$.

In base $n$, the "symbol" $78152_n$ represents the number

$78152_n=7\cdot n^4 + 8\cdot n^3 + 1\cdot n^2 + 5\cdot n^1 + 2\cdot n^0$.

You can see that we prefer to call a base by the number that is raised to the power of its position from the last digit. That is why we call it the **base**.

Comment: But wouldn't you still call it "base 10" if "10" referred to * * instead of to * * * * * * * * * * ?

Comment: But, then, isn't it always base 10? In binary, we stop counting at 1, the last digit, and then move to 10.

Comment: You should ask, "isn't it always base ten?"  No, it could be base two, base three, etc.

Comment: Yeah but in base 2, you don't have the number two to express two. To understand what I mean, it might help to work the other way. For e.g, in higher bases, say base 16, we express say 15 as F, but we not in base 10

Comment: @Simpson17866 Of course, when I said $10$ I was referring to "ten". :P

Comment: @littleO I like this new convention: always spelling out the number (two, three, ...) instead of using the base ten representation of the new base. We should make it more popular :)

Comment: @Simpson17866 You got me there.

Comment: @Simpson, yeah, I don't know why the naming conventions are so convoluted xD. See, my logic is is that if we called the base the final number that we use, then to me that's that. So for e.g, base 10 would be base 9 because 9 is the final number.

Comment: @user2901512 But when we deal with exponents, standard terminology is that the "base" is the number that's being raised to a power.  So with a base ten system, it's the number ten and not nine that is being raised to a power.  Hence "base ten". http://www.purplemath.com/modules/exponent.htm

Comment: @litteO, yeah but, that's what I mean... Maybe it shouldn't be like that. Well, that way seems to have multiple logical issues, because 10 is a universal number throughout all base systems.

Answer (score 11):

You're mixing the actual number with its representations. Yes, in base $n$, the string $10$ represents exactly $n$.

But now forego of the decimal representation of $10$, and think about it as "how many digits a healthy human being has on both their hands". This is your $n$, now. Let's for the sake of simplicity call this number "ten".

Now we are counting in base ten, and that's that. We are taught to innately think in terms of this base, which is why we call it base $10$.

Comment: What do we call other bases though? I don't mean just the 'popular' one's, like binary, or octal, or hexadecimal, how would we come up with a name?

Comment: @user, usually we contort ourselves and come up with an appropriate Latin or Greek prefix to prepend to "-ary"... :)

Comment: @user2901512 Would calling them *base two*, *base eight* and *base sixteen* not work well? The upshot is that *ten* has an unambigous meaning without reference to any base but the meaning of $10$ varies from base to base.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen What if we just called base 10 base 9? Infact, if we called any given base, where n = the last unique number, then we can just call it base n.

Comment: We call it "ten" because that's the number that comes after "nine". We have ten fingers, so the ancients counted them as one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten. There's no mathematical reason why we go "eight, nine, ten" and not "glarb, foo, blek"; it's just how the words evolved through history.

Comment: @Cole: While it is tempting to argue that because we have ten fingers, we count in base ten, it is probably false. Many ancient cultures counted in base 60, and some bushmen tribes in Africa do not have names for specific numbers, even those we can represent on a single hand (and look at little children having difficulty counting above three (also "this many!" with *some* fingers raised)). But in the modern society we *are* being taught to innately count in base ten.

Comment: @ColeJohnson, no I get that, it's not the symbols you use (within reason) but the idea behind them i.e abstraction. The issue here is one of consistency. In assigning a name to base n, it becomes difficult because it's always something like 'binary', or 'hexadecimal', I prefer base 1 and base 15 respectively (because hexadecimal has 15 unique char).

Comment: @user: The point is that the name of the number is not the same as its representation. However, as we treat the decimal base as universal (probably due to the fact we all have ten fingers, ideally), it is easy to decide that we can also say "base $n$" where $n$ is the decimal representation of the number $n$. This is convention, nothing more, to allow us to communicate with one another coherently.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila Convention should not be used as the premise in an argument with which one draws a conclusion, because we only progress by breaking it.

Comment: @user2901512: I'm sorry, but tough luck for you, then. *Everything* begins with conventions. Why do we chose the inference rules as we did? We did we call $0$ "zero" and not "flugelhorn"? Why is Hausdorff space "every two points have disjoint open sets separating them" and not "every cover has a finite subcover"? These are **all** conventions, used to communicate the ideas between one mathematician to another in an unambiguous.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila, the issue wasn't what we call things, like bases, but the protocol for doing so. It's about consistency, and calling base 10 is inconsistent. Take the octal numbering system, it's called base 8 but uses 7 char.

Comment: And we *are* consistent when we refer to base n with the decimal expression of n.  There is nothing inconsistent or ambiguous about it.

Comment: @fleablood When using the decimal notation, it can be ambiguous for some. Think about when you first learned base 2 by using 1's and 0's. It's also inconsistent symbolically.

Comment: Um... no it wasn't?  I knew each place represented powers of a number chosen to be base representative of the number system-- the number I referred to in my native numbering system as 2 and which will be represented in its base system as 10.  There was absolutely *nothing* inconsistant or ambiguous at all.

Comment: @user2901512: You're insisting that there is a problem, where historically this is evidently not the case. Yes, if I insist to interpret everything in base eleven, it is going to start being weird. But until someone does that, on purpose, and also tries to be a contributing mathematician (and not just a mathematical troll), then let's talk again.

Comment: @AsafKaragila There's no point arguing with you, because you form your premises of convention without stating why current convention is a good thing to begin with, and then you attack your opponent rather than his content. Despite all this, you end your correspondence by saying we should talk again when I have met some sort of standard which you have set above me, as I look up to you on your pedestal.

Comment: @user2901512: I didn't attack you. I am saying that all mathematical communication is based on convention. And deviating from the convention without a good reason is essentially trying to be confusing to other mathematicians, and doing so is essentially mathematical trolling. Because mathematics is a social activity, and we have established a common language. If you don't like that, then tough luck. Good luck in your lonesome mathematical activities based on base fifteen.

Comment: Once again, you're attacking the opponent, on multiple accounts. I have presented what I think is good reason,  and whilst initially you made an attempt at resolving said reason, it seems that this is now not the case. Oh, by the way, it seems that you have contradicted yourself, you quote 'base 15', presumably as a stab at me, however, you previously said that 'You're mixing the actual number with its representations', however here it seems you disregard that completely.

Comment: @user2901512: You are not in an uncommon situation. You have some idea about mathematics, but you're not a mathematician, and this idea is fundamentally wrong. Now you have to come to terms with that. I cannot help you any further.

Comment: @Asaf 'Your not a mathematician', 'this is fundamentally wrong'. Have I mistaken you for god? Is it possible that you can provide evidence or should I just take your word for it?

Comment: @user2901512: I'm done arguing with you. I gave you an answer, other people tried to explain it as well. You are obviously in a much better position than me to make statements about this, and I will concede that whatever you claim is going to be correct. Now let me return to doing mathematics and communicating it by the conventions of my community and my peers. Best of luck in your future endeavors.

Answer (score 2):

When I work with numbers in base 16 or base 2, the string "10" is not *called* "ten", but "one zero". We generally don't have names for specific integers that reflect some other base, so although a full 16 bit value is ffff and then 1 0000 is significant to me, I don't have a spoken name for it that corresponds to *thousand*.  It's only known as "sixty four K", which is nothing like how it's written.

The spoken "sixteen" refers to the specific natural number, no matter how else it is noted. The English name comes from a base-10 herritage, but we *could* have had a special word for it that stands alone, like *dozen*, *gross*, or *mole*.  Maybe someone will introduce one and it will catch on.

Comment: Ah but you see, this isn't an issue with what we call the numbers in other bases, as Asaf says, we use base 10 as the standard. The matter is what we call the bases, if base 10 is base 10 because we round to 10, then every base is base 10, apart from some exceptions like binary, octal, etc. Now, we do have names for the first n bases, but no names for anything beyond base n (whatever n means). So for e.g, what is base 15, 17, 23, 101?  We can't just keep coming up with new names like binary, it becomes impractical.

Comment: Note also the logical inconsistency between how we call binary base 2, and decimal base 10. In the latter, we do so because it's the next number in base 10, but in base 10, we do so because it's what we round up to. So not only is it logically inconsistent, but introduces complexities further down the line for other bases.

Comment: Round up to? I don't understand. Inconsistent,  no: regardless of the *name* or current notation in use, the integer that serves as the *base* of the polynomial is the successor of the largest one used for a single digit. If "ten" bothers you, use the chinese symbol 十 instead.

Comment: ''the integer that serves as the base of the polynomial is the successor of the largest one used for a single digit''. If that were the case though, then base 10 would be called base 9, and Binary would be referred to as base 1.

Comment: Are you not paying attention? 9 is the largest digit, the *successor* of that is ten, not nine again.  No number is its own successor.

Comment: @JDlogosz, yeah I totally misread that at the time, thanks. Anyway, wouldn't that mean though that by that logic, every base is base 10, since 10 is the successor of every last single digit, in any given base?

Comment: Yes, every base writes itself as `10` in that base. You successfully understand the tee-shirt "there are 10 kinds of people: those who understand binary and those who don't".  But **we don't pronounce that number as "ten"** just because it is spelled the same as how *ten* looks in our usual base. That is what this post is explaining.