# Logic behind the hexadecimal number system?

Tags: binary, number-systems

I am at the point where I understand binary quite well, so I decided to look at the hexadecimal numerical system, but I'm a bit stumped with the logic behind it. For those of you who understand it, you know that numbers 10 through 15 (decimal) are represented by letters A  through F respectively within the hexadecimal system. Within the binary system the number 31 is represented as $11111$ or $ 2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2 + 2^3 + 2^4 $. If I try to apply this same logic to the hexadecimal system it doesn't work because $ 1 = 1 $ and $ F = 15 $ but $ 1F  = 31 $ based on hexadecimal logic. Could someone explain why this is?

(Sorry if this super basic, I just can't wrap my head around it.)

Comment: $1F_{16}$ in decimal is just $1 \times 16^1 + 15 \times 16^0 = 31$.

Comment: Lol, thanks. I knew it was less complicated than I was making it.

Comment: 1F should absolutely be determined, logically, to be 31 just as you would with binary, but swap the 2's for 16's!

Comment: I could not figure out what your question was then I read Ross Millikan's answer and saw that it solved your problem. It would be kind of nice to know what your question was. I can only make a guess. Maybe you just made a mistake that in hexadecimal, 1F = 10 because 1 + F = 0, but in actuality, 1F = 10 + F, not 1 + F.

Comment: @Timothy Yeah, that was basically the issue. I just was having trouble understanding how the system works. I haven't looked at this question in so long, it even took me a second to remember what I was asking, lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is like positional notation in decimal.  Each digit to the left is worth $16$ times more than the one on the right, so $1F_{16}=1\cdot 16+15\cdot 1=31$  For a larger example, note that the third digit is worth $16\cdot 16=256$, so $ABC_{16}=10\cdot 256+11\cdot 16+12=2748$

Answer (score 1):

You might find it more helpful to compare it to the decimal system you are also familiar with, where the number written as $d_k d_{k-1} \dotsm d_2 d_1 d_0$ (where each $d_i$ is between $0$ and $9$ inclusive) means $10^0 d_0 + 10^1 d_1 + 10^2 d_2 + \dotsb + 10^{k-1}d_{k-1} + 10^k d_k  $: in hexadecimal you have
$$ h_k h_{k-1} \dotsm h_2 h_1 h_0 \text{ means } 16^0 h_0 + 16^1 h_1 + 16^2 h_2 + \dotsb + 16^{k-1}h_{k-1} + 16^k h_k, $$
where each $h_i$ is now an integer between $0$ and $F$ (or $15$) inclusive.